# Xubuntu - Apps Become Unresponsive Intermittently

Tags: 12.04, ati, xubuntu, window-manager, workspaces

Possibly Relevant Information:

- XUbuntu 12.04 LTS (precise)
- XFCE 4.8
- AMD Graphics (Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci, Kernel modules: fglrx, radeon)

The primary symptom of this issue has been my active rdesktop session to stop responding while everything else appears to work normally.  I have been killing rdesktop and re-launching it, with it freezing after a seemingly random time period.  The fastest was within seconds.  The longest was a couple hours, although it's usually within a few minutes.

That being said, I have occasionally seen the terminal and web browsers also become unresponsive to keyboard input.  They respond to clicks and will accept middle clicks (to paste text) without issue while remaining unresponsive to the keyboard input.

I have been able to restore functionality, by switching workspaces and typing on the other workspace, then returning to the original workspace.  This work-around typically does not work for rdesktop, although it has fixed rdesktop's functionality twice.

What is being reset when I do this?  What does this work-around/solution indicate may be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this problem has been known for quite some time.  I found the following bug threads on Ubuntu:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rdesktop/+bug/217868
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rdesktop/+bug/218308

In my case, killing the cisco vpn agent solved the problem.  If the agent was running, with or without an established connection, the freezes would occur.  Having killed the agent, it has been running over 24 hours without an issue.

```
Thu Nov 07 - 11:00 $ ps aux | grep vpn
root     12972  0.0  0.0  41420  2716 ?        S    11:00   0:00 /opt/cisco/vpn/bin/vpnagentd
```

I would add that these two pieces of software had worked fine for many months before this issue arose.